# How to remove script from page when there is no xml or phtml files?

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

I have a `Anaraky_GDRT 1.0.10` (Google Dynamic Remarketing) installed. Also I've got AMP pages set up using `Design/ Matched Expression` in Magento admin. AMP pages can't have any scripts on them but the way `Anaraky_GDRT` is made is that the script is added in `app/code/community/Anaraky/Gdrt/Block/Script.php` which adds the script globally. I've been adding basically blank XML files in my AMP directory to get rid of any scripts or blank phtml files.  But I can't figure a way to remove the `Anaraky_GDRT` script as it doesn't have any XML or phtml files in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout`

Here is the script file that adds the Google Dynamic Remarketing Tag in `app/code/community/Anaraky/Gdrt/Block/Script.php`:

```
<?php
class Anaraky_Gdrt_Block_Script extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract {

    private $_storeId = 0;
    private $_pid = false;
    private $_pid_prefix = "";
    private $_pid_prefix_ofcp = 0;
    private $_pid_ending = "";
    private $_pid_ending_ofcp = 0;

    private function getEcommProdid($product)
    {
        $ecomm_prodid = (string)($this->_pid ? $product->getId() : $product->getSku());
        $ofcp = false;
        if ($product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE ||
            $product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_GROUPED)
        {
            $ofcp = true;
        }

        if (!empty($this->_pid_prefix) && (($this->_pid_prefix_ofcp === 1 && $ofcp) ||
            $this->_pid_prefix_ofcp === 0))
        {
                $ecomm_prodid = $this->_pid_prefix . $ecomm_prodid;
        }

        if (!empty($this->_pid_ending) && (($this->_pid_ending_ofcp === 1 && $ofcp) ||
            $this->_pid_ending_ofcp === 0))
        {
                $ecomm_prodid .= $this->_pid_ending;
        }

        return $ecomm_prodid;
    }

    private function getParams()
    {
        if ((int)Mage::getStoreConfig('gdrt/general/gdrt_product_id', $this->_storeId) === 0)
            $this->_pid = true;

        $this->_pid_prefix = Mage::getStoreConfig('gdrt/general/gdrt_product_id_prefix', $this->_storeId);
        $this->_pid_prefix_ofcp = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('gdrt/general/gdrt_product_id_prefix_ofcp', $this->_storeId);
        $this->_pid_ending = Mage::getStoreConfig('gdrt/general/gdrt_product_id_ending', $this->_storeId);
        $this->_pid_ending_ofcp = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('gdrt/general/gdrt_product_id_ending_ofcp', $this->_storeId);

        $inclTax = false;
        if ((int)Mage::getStoreConfig('gdrt/general/gdrt_tax', $this->_storeId) === 1)
            $inclTax = true;

        $type = $this->getData('pageType');
        $params = array('ecomm_pagetype' => 'siteview');
        switch ($type) {
            case 'home':
                $params = array( 'ecomm_pagetype' => 'home');
                break;

            case 'searchresults':
                $params = array( 'ecomm_pagetype' => 'searchresults');
                break;

            case 'category':
                $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
                $params = array(
                    'ecomm_pagetype' => 'category',
                    'ecomm_category' => (string)$category->getName()
                );
                unset($category);
                break;

            case 'product':
                $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
                $totalvalue = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice(), $inclTax);

                $params = array(
                    'ecomm_prodid' => $this->getEcommProdid($product),
                    'ecomm_pagetype' => 'product',
                    'ecomm_totalvalue' =>  (float)number_format($totalvalue, '2', '.', '')
                );
                unset($product);
                break;

            case 'cart':
                $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
                $items = $cart->getAllVisibleItems();

                if (count($items) > 0) {
                    $data  = array();
                    $totalvalue = 0;
                    foreach ($items as $item)
                    {
                        $data[0][] = $this->getEcommProdid($item->getProduct());
                        $data[1][] = (int)$item->getQty();
                        $totalvalue += $inclTax ? $item->getRowTotalInclTax() : $item->getRowTotal();
                    }

                    $params = array(
                        'ecomm_prodid' => $data[0],
                        'ecomm_pagetype' => 'cart',
                        'ecomm_quantity' => $data[1],
                        'ecomm_totalvalue' => (float)number_format($totalvalue, '2', '.', '')
                    );
                }
                else
                    $params = array( 'ecomm_pagetype' => 'siteview' );

                unset($cart, $items, $item, $data);
                break;

            case 'purchase':
                $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(
                                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
                                            ->getLastRealOrderId());

                $data  = array();
                $totalvalue = 0;
                $items = $order->getAllItems();

                foreach ($items as $item)
                {
                    $data[0][] = $this->getEcommProdid($item->getProduct());
                    $data[1][] = (int)$item->getQtyToInvoice();
                    $totalvalue += $inclTax ? $item->getRowTotalInclTax() : $item->getRowTotal();
                }

                $params = array(
                    'ecomm_prodid' => $data[0],
                    'ecomm_pagetype' => 'purchase',
                    'ecomm_quantity' => $data[1],
                    'ecomm_totalvalue' => (float)number_format($totalvalue, '2', '.', '')
                );
                unset($order, $items, $item);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return $params;
    }

    private function paramsToJS($params)
    {
        $result = array();

        foreach ($params as $key => $value)
        {
            if (is_array($value) && count($value) == 1)
                $value = $value[0];

            if (is_array($value))
            {
                if (is_string($value[0]))
                    $value = '["' . implode('","', $value) . '"]';
                else
                    $value = '[' . implode(',', $value) . ']';
            }
            elseif (is_string($value))
                $value = '"' . $value . '"';

            $result[] = $key . ': ' . $value;
        }

        return PHP_EOL . "\t" . implode(',' . PHP_EOL . "\t", $result) . PHP_EOL;
    }

    private function paramsToURL($params)
    {
        $result = array();

        foreach ($params as $key => $value)
        {
            if (is_array($value))
                $value = implode(',', $value);

            $result[] = $key . '=' . $value;
        }

        return urlencode(implode(';', $result));
    }

    private function paramsToDebug($params)
    {
        $result = '';

        foreach ($params as $key => $value)
        {
            if (is_array($value) && count($value) == 1)
                $value = $value[0];

            if (is_array($value))
            {
                if (is_string($value[0]))
                    $value = '["' . implode('","', $value) . '"]';
                else
                    $value = '[' . implode(',', $value) . ']';
            }
            elseif (is_string($value))
                $value = '"' . $value . '"';

            $result .= '<tr>' .
                '           <td style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;">' . $key . ': &nbsp;</td>' .
                '           <td style="text-align:left;"> ' . $value . '</td>' . 
                '        </tr>';
        }

        return $result;
    }

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $gcId = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('gdrt/general/gc_id', $this->_storeId);
        $gcLabel = trim(Mage::getStoreConfig('gdrt/general/gc_label', $this->_storeId));
        $gcParams = $this->getParams();

        $version = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->modules->Anaraky_Gdrt->version;

        $s = PHP_EOL .
            '<!-- Anaraky GDRT v.' . $version . ' script begin -->' . PHP_EOL .
            '<script type="text/javascript">' . PHP_EOL .
            '/* <![CDATA[ */' . PHP_EOL .
            'var google_tag_params = {' . $this->paramsToJS($gcParams) . '};' . PHP_EOL .
            'var google_conversion_id = ' . $gcId . ';' . PHP_EOL .
            (!empty($gcLabel) ? 'var google_conversion_label = "' . $gcLabel . '";' . PHP_EOL : '') .
            'var google_custom_params = google_tag_params;' . PHP_EOL .
            'var google_remarketing_only = true;' . PHP_EOL .
            '/* ]]> */' . PHP_EOL .
            '</script>' . PHP_EOL .
            '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.com/js/google/conversion.js">' . PHP_EOL .
            '</script>' . PHP_EOL .
            '<noscript>' . PHP_EOL .
            '<div style="display:inline;">' . PHP_EOL .
            '<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/' . $gcId . '/?value=0' . (!empty($gcLabel) ? '&amp;label=' . $gcLabel : '') . '&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0&amp;data=' . $this->paramsToURL($gcParams) . '"/>' . PHP_EOL .
            '</div>' . PHP_EOL .
            '</noscript>' . PHP_EOL .
            '<!-- Anaraky GDRT script end -->' . PHP_EOL;

        if ((int)Mage::getStoreConfig('gdrt/debug/show_info', $this->_storeId) === 1)
        {
            $lk = str_replace(' ', '', Mage::getStoreConfig('dev/restrict/allow_ips', $this->_storeId));
            $ips = explode(',', $lk);
            if (empty($ips[0]) || in_array(Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr(), $ips))
            {
                $s .= PHP_EOL .
                    '<div style="position:fixed; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; padding:5px 0; background:rgba(255, 208, 202, 0.8); border:1px solid #f92104;">' . PHP_EOL .
                    '    <table style="margin:0 auto;font-size:13px;color:#222;">' .
                    '        <tr>' .
                    '           <td rowspan="' . (count($gcParams) + 1) . '" style="vertical-align:middle;padding-right:40px;"><h3 style="margin:0;">Anaraky GDRT debug v.' . $version . '</h3></td>' .
                    '           <td style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;">Model/Controller/Action: &nbsp;</td>' .
                    '           <td style="text-align:left;"> ' . $this->getData('pagePath') . '</td>' . 
                    '        </tr>' .
                    $this->paramsToDebug($gcParams) .
                    '    </table>' .
                    '</div>';
            }
        }

        return $s;
    }
}
```

So my question is how can I remove the script from my AMP pages?

Here's something I tried various combinations of but it either removes the script from every page or not:

```
$url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (strpos($url,'amp') !== true){

        $s = PHP_EOL .
            '<!-- Anaraky GDRT v.' . $version . ' script begin -->' . PHP_EOL .
            '<script type="text/javascript">' . PHP_EOL .
            '/* <![CDATA[ */' . PHP_EOL .
            'var google_tag_params = {' . $this->paramsToJS($gcParams) . '};' . PHP_EOL .
            'var google_conversion_id = ' . $gcId . ';' . PHP_EOL .
            (!empty($gcLabel) ? 'var google_conversion_label = "' . $gcLabel . '";' . PHP_EOL : '') .
            'var google_custom_params = google_tag_params;' . PHP_EOL .
            'var google_remarketing_only = true;' . PHP_EOL .
            '/* ]]> */' . PHP_EOL .
            '</script>' . PHP_EOL .
            '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.angelsforeveryone.com/js/google/conversion.js">' . PHP_EOL .
            '</script>' . PHP_EOL .
            '<noscript>' . PHP_EOL .
            '<div style="display:inline;">' . PHP_EOL .
            '<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/' . $gcId . '/?value=0' . (!empty($gcLabel) ? '&amp;label=' . $gcLabel : '') . '&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0&amp;data=' . $this->paramsToURL($gcParams) . '"/>' . PHP_EOL .
            '</div>' . PHP_EOL .
            '</noscript>' . PHP_EOL .
            '<!-- Anaraky GDRT script end -->' . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is wrong `if (strpos($url,'amp') !== true)`. `strpos` returns the position of a string or `false` if not found.

Please try this instead:

```
if (strpos($url,'amp') === false) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That fixed it!  Thanks for the help and the module, it works great.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw ... it's not my module ... it's a free on from magento connect ... just hosted it on Github :)